# How to retrieve the auto generated id/key in Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nsdictionary

I am getting all the products in the firebase database with following approach but I need to get the auto generated key. What should I do to make that happen?

```
func fetchProducts(){
    self.ref.child("products").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        //print(snapshot)
        let proObject = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

        let description = proObject["description"] as! String
        let categories = proObject["category"] as! Array<String>
        let images = proObject["image"] as! Array<String>
        let name = proObject["name"] as! String
        let price = proObject["price"] as! Int
        let qty = proObject["qty"] as! Int

        let pro = Product(name: name, qty: qty, 
        images: images, price: price, category: categories, description: description)

        self.items.append(pro)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auto generated key is available in the `snapshot.key` property.

[Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot#key) for this property:

> The key of the location that generated this FIRDataSnapshot.